# Java Application Window is very slow

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Hi i have created a Java Application Windown where it should connect to the database and change orders status and also see them more in more detail. But for no reason the app went very slown and doesnt execute the UPDATE commands, Wheres the code:

```
/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public EstagioGUITeste() {
    initialize();
}

private Connection ligacao = null;
private JComboBox cbEstado;
private JTable table;

private void iniLigacao() {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/science4estagio";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";

    try {
        ligacao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}

private void closeLigacao() {
    try {
        if (ligacao != null) {
            ligacao.close();

        }
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1012, 403);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
    JPanel panelLogin = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelLogin, "panelLogin");
    GridBagLayout gbl_panelLogin = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panelLogin.columnWidths = new int[] { 225, 358, 225, 0 };
    gbl_panelLogin.rowHeights = new int[] { 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 48, 0 };
    gbl_panelLogin.columnWeights = new double[] { 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gbl_panelLogin.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    panelLogin.setLayout(gbl_panelLogin);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Login");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 32));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblNewLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 0;
    panelLogin.add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("User:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblNewLabel_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblNewLabel_1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridy = 2;
    panelLogin.add(lblNewLabel_1, gbc_lblNewLabel_1);

    txtUser = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtUser = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtUser.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_txtUser.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_txtUser.gridx = 1;
    gbc_txtUser.gridy = 2;
    panelLogin.add(txtUser, gbc_txtUser);
    txtUser.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblPassowrd = new JLabel("Password:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblPassowrd = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblPassowrd.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_lblPassowrd.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblPassowrd.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblPassowrd.gridy = 3;
    panelLogin.add(lblPassowrd, gbc_lblPassowrd);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    passwordField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                iniLigacao();
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2 ";
                    PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.getLocalizedMessage();
                }

                closeLigacao();

                iniLigacao();
                try {
                    PreparedStatement inst = ligacao
                            .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM utilizadorpassword WHERE User=? and Password=? ");
                    inst.setString(1, txtUser.getText());
                    inst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());
                    ResultSet resultado = inst.executeQuery();
                    int contador = 0;
                    while (resultado.next()) {
                        contador = contador + 1;

                    }
                    if (contador == 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Acesso Garantido\n");
                        CardLayout card = (CardLayout) frame
                                .getContentPane().getLayout();
                        card.show(frame.getContentPane(), "panelPrincipal");
                    } else if (contador > 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Utilizador e password duplicados");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Utilizador e/ou password errados");
                    }
                    inst.close();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Impossivel ligar à base de dados\n");
                    System.out.println(e1.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
                closeLigacao();
            }
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_passwordField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_passwordField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_passwordField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_passwordField.gridx = 1;
    gbc_passwordField.gridy = 3;
    panelLogin.add(passwordField, gbc_passwordField);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Entrar");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            iniLigacao();
            try {
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2;";
                PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.getLocalizedMessage();
            }

            closeLigacao();

            iniLigacao();
            try {
                PreparedStatement inst = ligacao
                        .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM utilizadorpassword WHERE User=? and Password=? ");
                inst.setString(1, txtUser.getText());
                inst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());
                ResultSet resultado = inst.executeQuery();
                int contador = 0;
                while (resultado.next()) {
                    contador = contador + 1;

                }
                if (contador == 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Acesso Garantido\n");
                    CardLayout card = (CardLayout) frame.getContentPane()
                            .getLayout();
                    card.show(frame.getContentPane(), "panelPrincipal");
                } else if (contador > 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Utilizador e password duplicados");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Utilizador e/ou password errados");
                }
                inst.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.out.println("Impossivel ligar à base de dados\n");
                System.out.println(e1.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            closeLigacao();

        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 1;
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 5;
    panelLogin.add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);

    JPanel panelPrincipal = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelPrincipal, "panelPrincipal");
    GridBagLayout gbl_panelPrincipal = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panelPrincipal.columnWidths = new int[] { 26, 44, 78, 169, 124, 69,
            24, 0 };
    gbl_panelPrincipal.rowHeights = new int[] { 66, 104, 41, 0 };
    gbl_panelPrincipal.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gbl_panelPrincipal.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            Double.MIN_VALUE };
    panelPrincipal.setLayout(gbl_panelPrincipal);

    JButton btnCarregarDados = new JButton("Recarregar dados");
    btnCarregarDados.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            iniLigacao();
            try {
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2;";
                PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
            cbEstado.setSelectedIndex(0);
            closeLigacao();
    }});
    JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\workspace\\Science4youTestes\\LogoPanelPrincipal.png"));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblNewLabel_2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_lblNewLabel_2.gridwidth = 5;
    gbc_lblNewLabel_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblNewLabel_2.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblNewLabel_2.gridy = 0;
    panelPrincipal.add(lblNewLabel_2, gbc_lblNewLabel_2);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnCarregarDados = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnCarregarDados.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_btnCarregarDados.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_btnCarregarDados.gridx = 5;
    gbc_btnCarregarDados.gridy = 0;
    panelPrincipal.add(btnCarregarDados, gbc_btnCarregarDados);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridwidth = 5;
    gbc_scrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 1;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 1;
    panelPrincipal.add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    JLabel lblOrganizarPor = new JLabel("Mostrar Estado:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblOrganizarPor = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblOrganizarPor.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_lblOrganizarPor.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_lblOrganizarPor.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblOrganizarPor.gridy = 2;
    panelPrincipal.add(lblOrganizarPor, gbc_lblOrganizarPor);

    cbEstado = new JComboBox();
    cbEstado.setMaximumRowCount(4);
    cbEstado.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Object selected = cbEstado.getSelectedItem();
            iniLigacao();
            if (selected.toString().equals("Pendente")) {
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2 WHERE Estado='P - Pendente' ORDER BY ID_Encomenda DESC";
                    PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    st.executeQuery();
                    st.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
            } else if (selected.toString().equals("Confirmada")) {
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2 WHERE Estado='C - Confirmada' ORDER BY ID_Encomenda DESC";
                    PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    st.executeQuery();
                    st.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
            } else if (selected.toString().equals("Anulada")) {
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2 WHERE Estado='X - Anulada' ORDER BY ID_Encomenda DESC";
                    PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    st.executeQuery();
                    st.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
            } else if (selected.toString().equals("Reembolsada")) {
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2 WHERE Estado='R - Reembolsada' ORDER BY ID_Encomenda DESC";
                    PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    st.executeQuery();
                    st.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
            } else if (selected.toString().equals("Enviada")) {
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2 WHERE Estado='S - Enviada' ORDER BY ID_Encomenda DESC";
                    PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    st.executeQuery();
                    st.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
            } else {
                iniLigacao();
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2";
                    PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
                cbEstado.setSelectedIndex(0);
                closeLigacao();

            }
            closeLigacao();
        }
    });
    cbEstado.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Enviada",
            "Reembolsada", "Pendente", "Confirmada", "Anulada" }));
    cbEstado.insertItemAt("", 0);
    cbEstado.setSelectedIndex(0);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_cbEstado = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_cbEstado.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_cbEstado.gridx = 2;
    gbc_cbEstado.gridy = 2;
    panelPrincipal.add(cbEstado, gbc_cbEstado);

    JButton btnAlterarEstado = new JButton("Alterar Estado");
    btnAlterarEstado.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private String targetSwitch;
        private long targetIDb;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                radPanel.add(btnEnv);
                radPanel.add(btnCon);
                radPanel.add(btnPen);
                radPanel.add(btnRee);
                radPanel.add(btnAnu);
                if(table.getSelectedRowCount()==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Não selecionou nada");
                }else {
                int resposta2 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                        radPanel, "Altere o Estado da Encomenda",
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
                if (resposta2 == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    int resposta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                            "Deseja alterar mesmo o estado da encomenda?",
                            "Confirme a eliminação",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if (resposta == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        Object targetIdteste = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
                        try {
                            targetIDb = (long) targetIdteste;
                        } catch (ClassCastException ce){
                            ce.getLocalizedMessage();
                            ce.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        iniLigacao();
                        try{
                            PreparedStatement stt = ligacao
                                    .prepareStatement("SELECT view_ecra2_bg.Estado FROM view_ecra2_bg WHERE ID_Encomenda_BG=?");
                            stt.setLong(1, targetIDb);
                            ResultSet resul = stt.executeQuery();
                            resul.next();                               
                            String estadoAtual =resul.getString(1);
                            if(estadoAtual == "S"){
                                btnEnv.setSelected(true);
                            }
                        }catch(SQLException se){
                            se.getLocalizedMessage();
                        }

                        closeLigacao();



                        iniLigacao();
                        try {
                            PreparedStatement stt = ligacao
                                    .prepareStatement("UPDATE view_ecra2_bg SET Estado_BG='?' WHERE ID_Encomenda_BG=?");
                            Object targetSwitcher = btnGrp.getSelection().getSelectedObjects();

                            if(btnEnv.isSelected()){
                                stt.setString(1, "S");
                                stt.setLong(2, targetIDb);
                                stt.executeUpdate();
                            }else if(btnCon.isSelected()){
                                stt.setString(1, "C");
                                stt.setLong(2, targetIDb);
                                stt.executeUpdate();
                            }else if(btnPen.isSelected()){
                                stt.setString(1, "P");
                                stt.setLong(2, targetIDb);
                                stt.executeUpdate();
                            }else if(btnRee.isSelected()){
                                stt.setString(1, "R");
                                stt.setLong(2, targetIDb);
                                stt.executeUpdate();
                            }else if(btnAnu.isSelected()){
                                stt.setString(1, "X");
                                stt.setLong(2, targetIDb);
                                stt.executeUpdate();
                            }else {

                            }
                            if (targetSwitch!=null) {
                                System.out.println(targetSwitch);
                                stt.setLong(2, targetIDb);
                                stt.executeUpdate();
                            }
                            iniLigacao();
                            try {
                                String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2";
                                PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                            } catch (SQLException se) {
                                se.getLocalizedMessage();
                            }
                            cbEstado.setSelectedIndex(0);
                            closeLigacao();
                          } catch (SQLException se) {
                            se.getLocalizedMessage();
                        } catch(NullPointerException ne){
                            ne.getLocalizedMessage();
                            ne.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        closeLigacao();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnAlterarEstado = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnAlterarEstado.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_btnAlterarEstado.gridx = 3;
    gbc_btnAlterarEstado.gridy = 2;
    panelPrincipal.add(btnAlterarEstado, gbc_btnAlterarEstado);
    JButton btnDetalhesDeEncomenda = new JButton("Detalhes de encomenda");
    btnDetalhesDeEncomenda.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private long targetIDb;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(table.getSelectedRowCount()==0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Não selecionou nada");
            }else {
            Object targetIdteste = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
            String targetNome = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString();
            try {
                targetIDb = (long) targetIdteste;
            } catch (ClassCastException ce){
                ce.getLocalizedMessage();
                ce.printStackTrace();
            }
            iniLigacao();
            try {
                String sql = "SELECT Nome_Item, Quantidade, Preço FROM view_ecra3_bg WHERE ID_Encomenda=?";
                PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                st.setLong(1, targetIDb);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                table_ecra2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                textNomeShow.setText(targetNome);
                textIdShow.setText(String.valueOf(targetIDb));

                Double precoTotal = 0.0;

                int numItems = table_ecra2.getRowCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
                    precoTotal += Double.parseDouble(table_ecra2
                            .getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                }
                textTotal.setText(precoTotal+"€");

            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
            CardLayout card = (CardLayout) frame.getContentPane().getLayout();
            card.show(frame.getContentPane(), "panelEncomenda");
            }
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnDetalhesDeEncomenda = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnDetalhesDeEncomenda.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_btnDetalhesDeEncomenda.gridx = 5;
    gbc_btnDetalhesDeEncomenda.gridy = 2;
    panelPrincipal.add(btnDetalhesDeEncomenda, gbc_btnDetalhesDeEncomenda);

    JPanel panelEncomenda = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelEncomenda, "panelEncomenda");
    GridBagLayout gbl_panelEncomenda = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panelEncomenda.columnWidths = new int[] { 181, 315, 20, 82, 184, 36, 0, 189, 73, 62, 0 };
    gbl_panelEncomenda.rowHeights = new int[] { 37, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    gbl_panelEncomenda.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gbl_panelEncomenda.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            Double.MIN_VALUE };
    panelEncomenda.setLayout(gbl_panelEncomenda);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\workspace\\Science4youTestes\\LogoPanelPrincipal.png"));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_label = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_label.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_label.gridwidth = 5;
    gbc_label.gridheight = 2;
    gbc_label.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_label.gridx = 0;
    gbc_label.gridy = 0;
    panelEncomenda.add(label, gbc_label);

                                    JLabel lblId_1 = new JLabel("ID:");
                                    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblId_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
                                    gbc_lblId_1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
                                    gbc_lblId_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
                                    gbc_lblId_1.gridx = 5;
                                    gbc_lblId_1.gridy = 0;
                                    panelEncomenda.add(lblId_1, gbc_lblId_1);

                            textIdShow = new JTextField();
                            textIdShow.setEditable(false);
                            GridBagConstraints gbc_textIdShow = new GridBagConstraints();
                            gbc_textIdShow.gridwidth = 2;
                            gbc_textIdShow.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                            gbc_textIdShow.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
                            gbc_textIdShow.gridx = 7;
                            gbc_textIdShow.gridy = 0;
                            panelEncomenda.add(textIdShow, gbc_textIdShow);
                            textIdShow.setColumns(10);

                    JLabel lblNome_1 = new JLabel("Nome:");
                    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNome_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
                    gbc_lblNome_1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
                    gbc_lblNome_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
                    gbc_lblNome_1.gridx = 5;
                    gbc_lblNome_1.gridy = 1;
                    panelEncomenda.add(lblNome_1, gbc_lblNome_1);

                                            textNomeShow = new JTextField();
                                            textNomeShow.setEditable(false);
                                            GridBagConstraints gbc_textNomeShow = new GridBagConstraints();
                                            gbc_textNomeShow.gridwidth = 2;
                                            gbc_textNomeShow.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                                            gbc_textNomeShow.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
                                            gbc_textNomeShow.gridx = 7;
                                            gbc_textNomeShow.gridy = 1;
                                            panelEncomenda.add(textNomeShow, gbc_textNomeShow);
                                            textNomeShow.setColumns(10);

                                    JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
                                    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
                                    gbc_scrollPane_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                                    gbc_scrollPane_1.gridwidth = 7;
                                    gbc_scrollPane_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
                                    gbc_scrollPane_1.gridx = 1;
                                    gbc_scrollPane_1.gridy = 2;
                                    panelEncomenda.add(scrollPane_1, gbc_scrollPane_1);

                                            table_ecra2 = new JTable();
                                            table_ecra2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {},
                                                    new String[] {}));
                                            scrollPane_1.setViewportView(table_ecra2);

                            JButton btnVoltarAoMenu = new JButton("Voltar ao menu Principal");
                            btnVoltarAoMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                    iniLigacao();
                                    try {
                                        String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2;";
                                        PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
                                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                                        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                                        CardLayout card = (CardLayout) frame.getContentPane().getLayout();
                                        card.show(frame.getContentPane(), "panelPrincipal");
                                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    closeLigacao();
                                }
                            });
                            GridBagConstraints gbc_btnVoltarAoMenu = new GridBagConstraints();
                            gbc_btnVoltarAoMenu.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
                            gbc_btnVoltarAoMenu.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
                            gbc_btnVoltarAoMenu.gridx = 1;
                            gbc_btnVoltarAoMenu.gridy = 3;
                            panelEncomenda.add(btnVoltarAoMenu, gbc_btnVoltarAoMenu);

                            JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("Total:");
                            GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTotal = new GridBagConstraints();
                            gbc_lblTotal.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
                            gbc_lblTotal.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
                            gbc_lblTotal.gridx = 5;
                            gbc_lblTotal.gridy = 3;
                            panelEncomenda.add(lblTotal, gbc_lblTotal);

                    textTotal = new JTextField();
                    textTotal.setEditable(false);
                    GridBagConstraints gbc_textTotal = new GridBagConstraints();
                    gbc_textTotal.gridwidth = 2;
                    gbc_textTotal.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    gbc_textTotal.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
                    gbc_textTotal.gridx = 7;
                    gbc_textTotal.gridy = 3;
                    panelEncomenda.add(textTotal, gbc_textTotal);
                    textTotal.setColumns(10);
}
```

}
thanks in advance

Comment: You are doing database operation on the Event Dispatch Thread which will block the GUI.

Answer (score 4):

There is a litany of problems...

## First...

Swing is a single threaded environment, this means that any time you perform a long running or blocking action within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, you are preventing from processing the Event Queue, which can make your application appear as it has frozen...cause it has

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

There are a number of ways you might fix this, but remember, Swing is also NOT thread safe, this means that any interaction, modification or creation of UI elements MUST be done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  One of the simpler ways to fix this is to use a `SwingWorker`, which allows you to `publish` updates to the UI and `process` the updates within the context of the EDT.

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details...

## Second...

`KeyListener` is not an appropriate listener to use with ANY text component, there is a list of reasons, but in your case, you can not guarantee that <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the action key for the platform, which could cause issues with some users (people get use to way things work and don't like it when you try and change it).

See [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for a more appropriate method for been notified when a field is "actioned"

## Third...

Resource management, basically, you creating a bunch of resources, but you are not managing them appropriately...

For example, this...

```
try {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2 ";
    PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
} catch (SQLException se) {
    se.getLocalizedMessage();
}
```

Should be more like...

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM view_ecra2 ";
try (PreparedStatement st = ligacao.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
} catch (SQLException se) {
    se.getLocalizedMessage();
}
```

The `try-with-resources` will ensure that the `PreparedStaement` and `ResultSet` are closed properly, this will ensure that the database isn't leaking resources, which could impact performance

See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

## Additional...

The functionality you use for the "password" and `Entrar` button appears to be the same, rather then duplicating the code, try writing a single method which you can call from both `ActionListener`s or even write a single `ActionListener` which can be applied to both components...

Using absolute paths, `lblNewLabel_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\workspace\\Science4youTestes\\LogoPanelPrincipal.png"));`, is a really bad idea, as the location of the resource is not likely to be the same for other computers.

A better solution would be to embed the resources within the application context.  With Eclipse and Netbeans, you can do this by putting the resources within the `src` directory of the project, this will then ensure that when the application is built, they will be bundled within the resulting jar file.

You will then need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` to load them, depending on your needs.

For example, if you placed the `LogoPanelPrincipal.png` in the `resources/images` directory within your projects `src` directory, you would need to use something like...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/images/LogoPanelPrincipal.png");
lblNewLabel_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

The reason for using `ImageIO.read` is because it will throw a `IOException` if the image can't be loaded, unlike `ImageIcon` which can fail silently if the image can't be loaded for some reason...

See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

NEVER store password information in the database unencrypted (really don't care if this is just something you're doing for yourself, you should always be following best practices where ever possible).

Instead of storing the password at all, you should generate some kind of hash (MD5 for example) for the password and send that to the database, this way you never send the password information across the wire, where it can be intercepted...

Comment: did you just write that for this question or it is a copy/paste from somewhere? You really deserve points for that explanation whether they are correct or not.

Comment: Profile with a 174K reputation woow. Anyway good response, too informative and helpful. I saw you are doing IOS programming if you need appstore optimization check this one http://bit.ly/1DZDzxC my current work.

Comment: Is it required for me to create class's for every Event Dispatching Thread? 
I dont seem to get how to connect them to the Application Windown because for the SwingWorker to work i need to create a class and extend them to the SwingWorker 
(" class MeaningOfLifeFinder extends SwingWorker<String, Object>")
Who do i do it in my code?
Sorry to bother, but i cant quite get the answer from my search

Comment: There is only one EDT. You can get back into the EDT by using something like SwinUtilitites.invokeLater(Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing database operation on the Event Dispatch Thread which will block the GUI.
You should use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for that.